# Searching for a possible idiom

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I was watchin the show "The Leftovers" and there is a scene where a woman is talking to a guy who was giving a survey to people. They were talking about the results. And he said that the responses he got made—and I'm only thinking that that is what said— "the frog fliers pop" but he said it with food in his mouth so I only Think that that's what he said.

Anyone know something similar?

Comment: http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-leftovers-2014

Comment: "I administered the new questionnaire to the parents of the other girls.
None of the fraud flags popped."

Comment: You're welcome. I figured you'd heard "pop" correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was "**make your eyes pop**".

To make someone's eyes pop means to surprise them greatly ([dictionary reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eyes+pop+out+of+head)). And "your eyes" could sound like "frog fliers", since the vowels are similar.

Would this fit the context of your quote?

Comment: No it is not, Rand. Tim answered it in a comment but thank you very much anyway.